# Android, donut shaped mana bar

Tags: android, graphics

I'd like to make a donut shaped mana bar. As the time passes the mana is increasing and it fills up the donut, clockwise and when i cast something it drops back.

I have 2 little problems with this. I don't know how to draw a donut shape and i have no idea how could i fill it up.

So i'd like to ask for your help guys,

Thanks!

Comment: I tried it with canvas.drawPath.. but i failed. I thought i could add points to it and then remove them but i did not find function to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the ring shape:

http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#shape

You can draw a partial arc.  If you want multiple colors try drawing a full ring underneath (perhaps for empty) then the changing one on top for current status.

Comment: thanks, the partial arc is the answer... my english vocabulary i poor i did not know what arc means